# SQL serial number by group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to have a data output that should generate a serial number by group. Consider the example below.

```
Name 
----
XXXX
XXXX
XXXX
YYYY
YYYY
ZZZZ
ZZZZ
ZZZZ
```

expected output:

```
SlNo  Name 
----  ----
1     XXXX
1     XXXX
1     XXXX
2     YYYY
2     YYYY
3     ZZZZ
3     ZZZZ
3     ZZZZ
```

tried using rownumber() but generates serial number within group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name)
FROM    mytable
```